# Reproducibility of random numbers (Python 2/random)

Tags: python, python-2.7, random, deterministic, reproducible-research

In [Python 2 documentation of the `random.seed()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) function I found a warning:

> If a hashable object is given, deterministic results are only assured
>   when PYTHONHASHSEED is disabled.

From https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHASHSEED I infer that the `-R` switch of the interpreter may have similar effect as `PYTHONHASHSEED`.

I have verified empirically, that random numbers seeded with small integers seems to be reproducible. So do hashes of small integers.

However, `int` is hashable. Is it stated explicitly in any trusted source, that it is safe to use it as a seed for a reproducible sequence of random numbers?

In contrast to [Reproducibility of python pseudo-random numbers across systems and versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786084/reproducibility-of-python-pseudo-random-numbers-across-systems-and-versions),  reproducibility within same system and interpreter is enough.

Comment: I would consider that a documentation flaw; it should say that ints and longs are not hashed. In any case, the Python 2 implementation is unlikely to change at this point, and the [Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed) mentions that ints (Python 2 longs) are used directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation confirms its safety in Python 2.6:

> If x is not None or an int or long, hash(x) is used instead. If x is an int or long, x is used directly.

(from https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/random.html#random.seed)

[EDIT]

The documentation for 2.7 has been updated to:

> If a is not None or an int or a long, then hash(a) is used instead. Note that the hash values for some types are nondeterministic when PYTHONHASHSEED is enabled.

Answer (score 3):

Not a complete answer but the source code for [`random_seed` (in C)](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/_randommodule.c#l237) would be relevent:

```
if (PyInt_Check(arg) || PyLong_Check(arg))
    n = PyNumber_Absolute(arg);
else {
    long hash = PyObject_Hash(arg);
    if (hash == -1)
        goto Done;
    n = PyLong_FromUnsignedLong((unsigned long)hash);
}
```

this would suggest that anything other then a `long` (int) directly uses the hash value as the seed, so as long as:

1. `hash(int)` gives consistent results and
2. You are using this implementation of seed (may not be the same for Jython etc.)

Then I'd expect `seed(int)` to yield consistent results.

That said I can't speak for either of those conditions staying constant so this doesn't really give a definitive answer unless someone else can verify them.

Comment: That looks like the Python 3 source code. The [Python 2 code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/_randommodule.c#l231) would be more relevant.

Comment: @user2357112 ok but other then checking if it is an `int` or `long` instead of just `long` the relevant parts are pretty much the same no?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I agree with user2357112. It is not about `int`/`long` difference. The question was about Python 2 specifically, so Python 2.7 source code seems more appropriate