# Python and R encode gives different result

Tags: python, r, encode

I'm translating an R script into Python, however, I found the encoding result is different between Python and R.

In R:

```
> digest('0003bf82df1e0255a352b89d431a831d_NA', algo='xxhash32')
[1] "d6865d43"
```

In Python:

```
>>> xxhash.xxh32('0003bf82df1e0255a352b89d431a831d_NA').hexdigest()
'3c0493fd
```

They both use the same algo and both with the default `seed = 0`. But why is this happening?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you're assuming r and python use the same rng by default?

Answer (score 2):

seed=0 will only give the same value stream when passed to the same random number generator on repeated instances.

Passing seed=0 to two different random number generators will give different value streams.

While it is true [R's random number generator](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/R_Programming/Random_Number_Generation#:%7E:text=Random%20Number%20Generators,-To%20a%20very&text=The%20default%20algorithm%20in%20R,learn%20about%20random%20number%20generators.&text=It%20is%20possible%20to%20use%20true%20random%20numbers.) and [Python's random number generator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) are both by default a [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) the underlying implementation is [demonstratively different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213298/creating-same-random-number-sequence-in-python-numpy-and-r).

Because the random number generation relies on some underlying implementation, [R is not even consistent across versions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56381613/15497888). [Python technically isn't either](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8786112/15497888) as, prior to Python2.3, it used a different random number generator, but all currently supported versions of python are consistent.

Comment: Good point, but FWIW I believe that it is just the *defaults* that are inconsistent across R versions (note that the link you give is specifically about the behaviour of `sample()`; for example, `RNGversion("2.0")` will set the random-number generation machinery to be identical to that used in R version 2.0.